# Showing that $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x>a$ and that $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x<a$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are functions that are differentiable on an open interval $I$.

Furthermore, suppose that $f'(x)>g'(x)$ for all x $\in I$ and that $f(a)=g(a)$ for some fixed number $a$ $\in I$.

I want to show $f(x)>g(x)$ for $x>a$ and that $f(x)<g(x)$ for $x<a$.

My approach: I'm thinking I can use contradiction on the fact that there are 2 points of tangency and somehow arrive to a contradiction of increase/decreasing and maybe applying mean value theory.

Comment: Simplify things for yourself by working with $h := f - g$.

Comment: What is the mean value theorem tell you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$, so $h(a)=0$ and $h'(x)>0$. Obviously $h(x)$ monotonically increases.

Comment: I think it would help this answer to drop the ‘obviously,’ instead demonstrating this fact for someone who’s most likely in the very early stages of analysis.